# The possibility of good qestions (by some measure) counting towards tag bages

Tags: discussion, badges, asking-questions

The important part of SO are the answers - which is why, reputation-wise, answer upvotes count twice as much as question upvotes. Still, SO (SX really) acknowledges the importance and the benefits of good questions, both by awarding reputation for merely asking them and for their popularity.

Now, I maintain that people who contribute to a (tagged) subject with thought-provoking poignant questions, which inspire useful answers, are generally  knowledgeable enough about the subject they're asking about to have some sort of professional authority about them. Not, perhaps, to the level of a Gold badge, but certainly to the level of a Bronze and maybe Silver badges.

On the other hand, a user asking "What are move semantics?" "What does yield do in Java?", and so on, might have a lot of votes but is no authority on anything C++ and Java. Still, perhaps some sort of measure regarding high-quality questions could or should be accounted for towards reaching a Bronze (or maybe also a Silver) tag badge.

PS - I'm biased here, as you'll note from my profile, since I've done a lot more asking than answering.

Comment: There are already 18 badges dedicated to questions.  Almost a million questions have the "Notable Question" silver badge for example.  Hard to see what you are asking for, just wait a bit longer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see what this would get us in terms of positive behaviour from users.

The tag badges are also called *expert badges*; you have proven to be an expert in the subject because you answered enough posts with enough of a score. But if you *asked* many such questions, you are not an expert, you are someone who asked questions about the subject, something we don't really have a shortage of.

We already have dedicated badges for asking good questions *over time*; the Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic badges; the latter can be earned more than once even. This is on top of the per-question badges; you can earn *loads* of badges per question (3 levels for score, views and favourite counts).

Comment: I'll give an exaggerated example. Two users, X and Y, answered 20 questions about tag T which got at least one upvote. User X answered them 5 years ago, user Y more recently. However, user X has asked questions regarding some finer points of the same subject, digging deeper etc. User X's answers collected upvotes overtime, more so than Y's, eventually reaching 100. I would argue that Y merits a tag badge more than X, although s/he would meet the criteria later.